# Unnecessary Recomposition in Jetpack Compose when Using Variable Reference Inside Lambda

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, compose-recomposition

I'm working on a Jetpack Compose application and I've encountered an issue with unnecessary recomposition when using a variable reference inside a lambda. Even if variable is not change, it triggers a recomposition while scrolling Lazy Column. This behavior is bothers me.

In this applicaiton i am using [Rafael Costa](https://github.com/raamcosta)'s [Compose Destination](https://composedestinations.rafaelcosta.xyz/) library.

1- In the Settings Screen i have several ListItem and all of there marked as `Modifier.clickable { }`. If i try to add `navigator.navigate(...)` it causes recomposition while scrolling even if DestinationsNavigator is marked as Stable. But when i use outside function like `Log.e(...)` it's working as expected.

2- In this screen i created context variable using `LocalContext.current`. When i try to make Toast message using this context it causes the same error.

Here is SettingsScreen:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Destination(style = ScreensAnim::class)
@Composable
fun SettingsScreen(
    navigator: DestinationsNavigator
) {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior()
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            LargeTopAppBar(title = {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.destination_settings_title),
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                    letterSpacing = TITLE_LETTER_SPACING
                )
            }, scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior)
        }
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            contentPadding = it,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            item(key = "buy_premium") {
                BuyPremiumButton(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
                        .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.large)
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer)
                        .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 16.dp, bottom = 4.dp),
                    onBuyNow = {
                        /*Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            context.getString(R.string.coming_soon),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()*/
                    },
                    onRestore = {

                    }
                )
            }
            item(key = "general") {
                ListItem(
                    headlineText = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_general_title)) },
                    supportingText = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_general_desc)) },
                    leadingContent = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.ToggleOn,
                            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_general_desc)
                        )
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable { navigator.navigate(GeneralScreenDestination) }
                )
            }
            item(key = "theme") {
                ListItem(
                    headlineText = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_theming_title)) },
                    supportingText = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_theming_desc)) },
                    leadingContent = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Palette,
                            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_theming_desc)
                        )
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable { navigator.navigate(ThemeScreenDestination) }
                )
            }

            item(key = "personalize") {
                ListItem(
                    headlineText = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_personalize_title)) },
                    supportingText = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_personalize_desc)) },
                    leadingContent = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Visibility,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            context.getString(R.string.coming_soon),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    }
                )
            }

            item(key = "backup") {
                ListItem(
                    headlineText = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_backup_title)) },
                    supportingText = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_backup_desc)) },
                    leadingContent = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.AddToDrive,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            context.getString(R.string.coming_soon),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    }
                )
            }

            item(key = "app_language") {
                ListItem(
                    headlineText = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_app_language_title)) },
                    supportingText = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_app_language_desc)) },
                    leadingContent = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Language,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable { navigator.navigate(AppLanguageScreenDestination) }
                )
            }

            item(key = "user_language") {
                ListItem(
                    headlineText = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_user_language_title)) },
                    supportingText = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_user_language_desc)) },
                    leadingContent = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Translate,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable { navigator.navigate(UserLanguageScreenDestination) }
                )
            }

            item(key = "about") {
                ListItem(
                    headlineText = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_about_title)) },
                    supportingText = {
                        Text(
                            text = stringResource(
                                R.string.settings_about_desc,
                                stringResource(id = R.string.app_name)
                            )
                        )
                    },
                    leadingContent = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Info,
                            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_about_desc)
                        )
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable { navigator.navigate(AboutScreenDestination) }
                )
            }

            item {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(96.dp))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Unnecessary recomposition]

To illustrate the problem, let's say I have a composable function that takes a lambda as a parameter. Inside the lambda, I reference a variable (LocalContext, view model, navigator), but the lambda itself doesn't actually use this variable. However, whenever the variable changes, it triggers a recomposition of the composable, even though it's not necessary.

I've tried using `remember` and all other solutions in [this article](https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2022/08/05/jetpack-compose-recomposition/), these approaches haven't resolved the issue.

**Edit**

When i remove `.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection)` from Scaffold. Recomposition is not happening. Is this expected behavior or a Material3 bug?

```
Kotlin: 1.7.20
Compose: 1.3.1
Compose material: 1.1.0-alpha06
```

I'm looking for suggestions on how to avoid this. Is there a better way to handle this situation or any workarounds that can help optimize the performance of my application?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Recomposition occurs when the state has changed.
In your case, it was the clickable function in the modifier.

To solve this you need to add a LaunchedEffect when you want to navigate to another screen.
This way your screen will not recompose.

```
 LaunchedEffect(true) {
    navigator.navigate(GeneralScreenDestination)
}
```

Comment: This navigates on the first composition. 
This is not the same as having navigation onClick. Click handlers can have navigation calls.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. As @Abhimanyu said, i want to navigate on onClick event, this LaunchedEffect calls navigate function on the first composition.